# EF Core cannot install the Initial Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

These are the packages I have:

[image]

And this is my **global.json** file:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.101"
  }
}
```

And this is my **project file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now I am trying to run this command but I get an error. What am I missing?

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

Error I get:

```
A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [3.1.101] from [C:\MyRepoz\SportsSln\SportsStore\global.json] was not found
Install the [3.1.101] .NET Core SDK or update [C:\MyRepoz\SportsSln\SportsStore\global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
  1.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.512 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was that it specifically needs version **3.1.1** of .NET Core SDK.
So I went to their website and downloaded it and installed it.

Website is this: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `dotnet` is not recognised (you can verify it by typing `dotnet --list-sdks`, which should produce same error).

The solution should be to add env variable to PATH which points to the directory that contains SDKs. On Windows x64, this should be `C:\Program Files\dotnet`.

Also verify that `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101` actually exists.